# How do you test a statement with no return React Jest Enzyme

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs, enzyme

I am learning jest, enzyme and i just cant figure out something so simple. My problem is that this condition is inside of another function. I need to check if the state obj is not null then assign some variables and test it. When I check code coverage it shows that the if statement is not covered. thanks

```
async handleButton() {

if (this.state.obj !== null) {
   var employee = this.state.obj.employee.name;
   var employeeId = this.state.obj.employee.id;
 }
await this.setState({
   updateObj: {...someOldObj, employee, employeeId};
 });
}
```

Comment: that `if` block, if it like that in your actual code, is completely useless anyway as nothing happens inside it - two variables are declared and assigned, but then thrown away as the scope ends straight away. Did you perhaps mean to adjust outer variables? If so, drop the `let`s and just keep the assignments.

Comment: @RobinZigmond - wouldnt that if block prevent an error from happening? incase its null, then the variables there wont be throwing error

Comment: not sure what you've mean - but I see you've edited to replace the `let` with `var`. That may work now, although it will probably be better if the `var` is removed and just the assignments are left, as I first suggested (although much depends on where/how these 2 variables are declared outside). In any case, my original comment now no longer applies.